# How to set parameter to loop from specific row in excel using python

Tags: python, nlp

The code read data from specific column in excel column ( in my case i used columns = 'profile') 
The result is in dataframe as below:

```
profile
0  https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/...
1  https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/...
2  https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/...
```

So, I try to loop the data in dataframe. My problem is the algorithm includes the header (profile) as well, so it turns error. Below is my work:

```
results = []

for result in df :
    result = CF.face.detect(result) 
    if result == []:                          
        #do something
    else:
        #do something  
    print(results)
```

The error I got from this code is (invalid as it loop the 'profile' as well):

```
  status_code: 400                                                       
        code: InvalidURL
        code: InvalidURL
        message: Invalid image URL.
```

My question is, how to write the code so it will loop all the data within column (excluding the 'profile')? I am not sure if put 'df' in 'for result in df ' is a correct way or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through one column in the the dataframe, you can refer to it and then write your loop

```
for result in df['profile'] :
   result = CF.face.detect(result) 
   if result == []:                          
       #do something
   else:
       #do something  
   print(results)
```